# How to align columns in lstlisting with breaklines=true?

Tags: listings, line-breaking, code, alignment

The issue is indicated in red below.

[image]

I can guess the right indent with `breakindent` in `pt`, but there has to be a better way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  columns=flexible,
  keepspaces=true,
  %breakindent=20.9pt,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
IIII IIII IIII IIII IIII IIII
IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII
    IIIIII IIIIII IIIIII
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a value expressed in 'em' units: that unit is directly related to the width of the uppercase 'M' (at least in theory), and, as listings uses a monospaced font, that's also the width of the 'I' (+ letterspace). (An alternative definition makes 1em equal to the font size, but in both cases you have a unit that changes with the selected font size).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\settowidth{\dimen0}{\ttfamily I}%
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breakindent=4\dimen0,
  columns=flexible,
  keepspaces=true,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
IIII IIII IIII IIII IIII IIII
IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII IIIII
    IIIIII IIIIII IIIIII
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

assuming you want 4 "spaces" as the indent. It would be different if you use, say `\small` in your listings style, then you need to recalculate the width of a `\small` tt "I", for example.

Comment: I'm accepting @remco's answer because its implementation is shorter. I didn't know about `\settowidth`, which may be very useful in other contexts. Thanks!